# Geodesics as a local frame of reference

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

Consider an arbitrary 2D pseudo-Riemannian space (spacetime) with a metric signature of $(1,1)$. I want to construct an orthogonal frame of reference of a free moving body. Obviously my time axis would be a time-like geodesic, along which the body is moving. Would my space axis be along one of space-like geodesics?

More specifically, my question is local. I am only interested in the infinitesimal movement of the body. So my momentary time axis is a tangent vector to the time-like geodesic of the body movement. Is my orthogonal space axis a tangent vector to one of the space-like geodesics intersecting at the point of origin?

Intuitively this seems obvious, but I just wanted to confirm if this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that *every* vector defined at a point $p$ is tangent to some geodesic through the point $p$. So if you only care about the observer's basis at a single point, there is nothing to answer.

If, however, you care about the observer's coordinate system in some *neighbourhood* of the point $p$, then the answer to your question depends on what kind of observer we're considering. The coordinates of an observer in a *local inertial frame* are [normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates), which are defined in such a way that the coordinate axes are indeed geodesics.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I will review the link you provided. Yes, I am interested in the neighbourhood of the point where the geodesics are asymptotically straight. Also could you please clarify what you mean by "what kind of observer"? The observer is in a free flight along a timeline geodesic. What additional information can I provide to specify its "kind"? Thanks again!

Comment: I have posted a follow-up question. I would appreciate if you take a look. Thanks! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2568882/find-local-orthogonal-coordinates-based-on-the-global-metric-and-geodesics

Comment: Dependent on whether your observer follows a geodesic or not, and dependent on whether that observer is rotating or not, the above statement about spatial axes may not be true. I was largely covering my back here, because my suspicion is that *all* physical observers have spacelike geodesics for coordinate axes, but don't quote me on that. You might like to read my answer to this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/307466/physical-meaning-of-frames-in-general-relativity/307549#307549.

Comment: Yes, my observer follows a timeline geodesic and is not rotating in this question.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. I've poseted a related follow-up question and would appreciate if you have any insight: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572957/can-a-curvilinear-frame-of-reference-be-defined