# Find local orthogonal coordinates based on the global metric and geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Consider a Euclidean space $X={\Bbb R}^2$ equipped with a known global $(1,1)$ pseudo-Riemannian metric in non-Cartesian coordinates. I need to define a local orthogonal Cartesian coordinate system of an observer located at a point $P$. When the observer is in a free flight moving along a timelike geodesic, his momentary time axis is  tangent to this geodesic. How can I find his space axis? I am interested in the local limit where the geodesics are asymptotically straight. I would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When coordinates are involved, you can think of the metric $g$ as a matrix: for two vectors $v, w$, the inner-product is $$g^{ij}v_iw_j = v_ig^{ij}w_j = \langle v, gw\rangle$$
where $\langle\,\,,\,\rangle$ is the ordinary Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^n$. This is true whether $g$ is Riemannian or pseudo-Rimannian.

So in your case, just multiply the timelike vector by $g$, then find the Euclidean orthogonal to the result to get the spacelike vector.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not a mathematician and am a bit rusty with conventions of how things are written, so I hope you could help me understand the answer. When you say, "multiply the timeline vector by g", g here is in a diagonal matrix, right? And then how do I find the Eucledian orthogonal in a hyperbolic space? Sorry, I know this is simple once I get it, so I hope you can push me over this roadblock :)

Comment: No, $g$ need not be diagonal. $$g = \begin{bmatrix} g^{11} & g^{12}\\g^{21} & g^{22} \end{bmatrix}$$ The metric defines an inner product $$g\langle v, w\rangle = \sum_{ij} g^{ij}v_iw_j$$ As is normal in differential geometry, I used the Einstein summation convention to drop the sum signs. But note that $\sum_j g^{ij} w_j$ gives the $i$th component of the vector $u := gw$. and so the whole sum is $\sum_i v_iu_i$, which is just the normal Euclidean inner product. And note that the *space* itself is neither hyperbolic nor Euclidean. It is the inner products that define these characteristics.

Comment: So you don't find the "Euclidean orthogonal in a hyperbolic space". You find the Euclidean orthogonal, period. For two dimensions, there is only one such orthogonal, up to a multiple: $(x, y) \perp (y, -x)$. But you apply it to $gw$, after the affects of the hyperbolic inner product $g$ have been applied.

Comment: And one other thing you should learn: it is "timelike", not "timeline".

Comment: Thanks again Paul! Let me try digesting this and I might bother you one more time if I still struggle. Sorry about the "timeline" typo, it is the dumb spellchecker changing what I type :) Thanks for catching it, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Not a problem - but I wasn't sure if it was a repeated typo or if you were actually confused about the terminology. If the latter, I thought you should know what was actually being said, as both "timeline" and "timelike" are used, but mean different things. That's why I pointed it out.

Comment: So, in the Minkowski space example, I multiply a timelike vector ($v\lt c$) by the metric: $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}t\\vt\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}t\\-vt\end{pmatrix}$ and then apply $(x, y) \rightarrow (y, -x)$ to get the orthogonal spacelike vector: $\begin{pmatrix}vt\\t\end{pmatrix}$. Makes sense. Did I get it right? (Ignoring the units of measurement, of course, c=1.)

Comment: A quick question to clarify the matrix form of the metric to use above. I don't need to include the coordinate parts of the metric (like $dt^2$ or $dx^2$), right? For example, for the 2D Rindler metric $ds^2=(ax)^2dt^2-dx^2$ the matrix form is $\begin{bmatrix} (ax)^2 & 0\\0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$. Is this correct? Thanks for all your insight, it's been enormously helpful! :)

Comment: Yes to both questions. In the first, the metric-induced inner product is $g\langle v, w\rangle = v_1w_1 - v_2w_2$. When $v = \begin{pmatrix}t\\vt\end{pmatrix}$ and $w = \begin{pmatrix}vt\\t\end{pmatrix}$, this is $(t)(vt) - (vt)(t) = 0$, so they are orthogonal. And in the second, you've already applied the $dt$ and $dx$ elements in writing $v =\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\end{pmatrix}$. I.e., $dt$ and $dx$ are actually functionals on the space of tangent vectors (linear functions from the vector space into the reals). $dt(v) = v_1, dx(v) = v_2$. So all the matrix rep shows is the coefficients.

Comment: Based on your answer I was able to perform the calculations I needed. Much appreciated!  I also have poseted a related follow-up question and I wonder if you have any insight: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572957/can-a-curvilinear-frame-of-reference-be-defined